# How to open a file dialog using javascript with CEF

Tags: chromium-embedded

I am learning CEF,and now I want to open a file dialog using my owner javascript code.Who can help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
virtual void RunFileDialog(
 FileDialogMode mode,
 const CefString& title,
 const CefString& default_file_path,
 const std::vector<CefString>& accept_filters,
 int selected_accept_filter,
 CefRefPtr<CefRunFileDialogCallback> callback) = 0;
```